# Getting a sprite to smoothly track a touchpoint

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make my sprite face and follow a touchpoint as it moves, and I've been successful so far. Basically, whenever the user touches the screen, my sprite will rotate to face the touch point, and move toward it. Here is my basic code:

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    //calculate tapPosition + angle, then rotate the sprite and move it to the tapPosition:

    [fish runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0 angle:angle]];
    [fish runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.8 position:tapPosition]];
}
```

Now the problem is that as this is in a `UIPanGesture`, this method is being run constantly as long as a finger is touching the screen. This actually makes the rotation and movement very choppy because a previous action is always being overridden by a new one.

Its not smooth and fluid. How can I make it smooth? Do I need to somehow delay some of my actions or something? Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use actions when you need to change the direction and movement constantly. Actions aren't good for this, and may even cause your object not to move at all when you stop/run new actions every frame.

Instead you'll have to calculate the object's velocity frame by frame and add that velocity to the position. From the velocity you can also calculate the angle (direction aka rotation).

Answer (score 0):

Use CCSequence & add this 2 animation in CCSequence object.
And add this CCSequence animation in your Sprite.

I hope this work good for you.